# helper function for char does not work as expected

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am solving reverse string problem. I wonder why the helper function for swapping 2 char does not work in my code. But it works if I write the code for swapping inside the while loop.

```
class Solution {
    public void reverseString(char[] s) {
        
        int left = 0;
        int right = s.length - 1;
        
        while (left < right) {
            swap(s[left], s[right]);
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }
    // not working as expected
    public void swap(char a, char b) {
        char temp = b;
        b = a;
        a = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is call-by-value. `a` and `b` are copies of what you pass in. If you change them inside of `swap`, these changes will not affect anything else than the scope of that method. Change your code so that `swap` operates on the array.

Answer (score 1):

Java is call-by-value. In `swap`, `a` and `b` are copies of what you pass in. If you change them inside of `swap`, these changes will not affect anything else than in the scope of that method.

Change your `swap` method so that it operates on the array directly:

```
public void swap(char[] s, int a, in b) {
    char temp = s[b];
    s[b] = s[a];
    s[a] = temp;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
swap(s, left, right);
```